# how to correctly compress expressions?

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

I don’t know mathematics well enough and I was faced with the task of rolling up such a thing. Could you tell me how to do this correctly?
$$ \frac{3}{x^3 + 1} + \frac{5}{x^3 + 1} + ... + \frac{2x + 1}{x^3 + 1} $$

[Original task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTAkh.png)

Comment: Should the numerator of the last term be $2n+1$ instead of $2x+1$?

Comment: @whpowell96 no, the unknown is the same in the numerator and denominator

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: if $x$ is an integer $\ge1$, $3+5+\cdots2x+1$ is a sum of $x$ terms averaging to $x+2$, so...

Comment: Can you clarify whether $x$ is restricted to be an integer? Otherwise it is a bit unclear what the intermediate terms should be

Comment: @whpowell96 i update question

Comment: I understood correctly that this is still the same arithmetic progression, which will collapse like $ \frac{ \frac{3}{x^3+1} + \frac{2x+1}{x^3+1}}{2} * x $ ?

Comment: To complement what @J.G. said, assuming $x$ is a positive integer, put everything over the same common denominator, after which you have a finite arithmetic series in the numerator.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yes, but in order to calculate the limit I need to first represent the sum by the expression

Comment: The series converges for $x \rightarrow \infty$ and the result is about $2.909791218786756475847\ldots$ (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28%282x%2B1%29%2F%28x%5E3%2B1%29%29%2C+x%3D1+to+infinity).

Comment: I think this will help.... $\sum_\limits{k=1}^n 2k-1 = n^2$

Comment: @MarcoRipà That's not the same problem.

Comment: *but in order to calculate the limit I need to first represent the sum by the expression* --- Google ["arithmetic series" + sum](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22arithmetic+series%22+sum). Several of the highest hits, at least for me, seem appropriate, such as [this web page](https://www.chilimath.com/lessons/advanced-algebra/arithmetic-series-formula/) ([internet archive version](https://web.archive.org/web/20231030191823/https://www.chilimath.com/lessons/advanced-algebra/arithmetic-series-formula/), in case the link goes dead in the future sometime).

Comment: Hint $3+5+\cdots +(2n+1) < (2n+1) + (2n+1)+\cdots (2n+1) = n(2n+1) = 2n^2+2n$ and if you divide quadratic polynomial by a cubic polynomial the limit would be ...

Comment: @jjagmath We agree that the limit is trivially equal to zero, but I do not understand why $n(2n+1)=2n^2+2n$ instead of $n(2n+1)=2n^2+n$ (I assume it is just a typo).

Comment: Yes, it's a typo, thank you.

Comment: @MarcoRipà using the hint given to you by user317176, you can see that the numerator is equal to $(x+1)^2$. What you have then is $\frac{(x+1)^2)}{x^3+1} = \frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^3+1}=\frac{x^2}{x^3+1}+\frac{2x}{x^3+1}+\frac{1}{x^3+1}$... can you see why the limit is $0$ now?

Comment: @H.sapiensrex I think you misunderstood the meaning of what I wrote above... I am not going to do basic high school homework here, I simply answered to a different question because the original question wasn't clear enough when you read it in a hurry. My point is that it is trivial to explain why $|\frac{P(x^2)}{P(x^3)}| \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. Regards, M

Comment: @MarcoRipà whoops, my apologies! I mistook your comment for one of OP's

Comment: @H.sapiensrex Oh, I see now. No problem at all!

Comment: @H.sapiensrex 
I'm understood, thank you